# How can I make sure an object is not in the database using Codeception?

Tags: symfony, codeception

I'm working on a Symfony application and writing some tests using CodeCeption.

I need to make sure some entities are created in the database, for which I need to make sure they don't exist previous to the execution of the method under test.

Is there something like:

```
$I->dontHaveInRepository($entity)
```

?

I've checked the docs but didn't find a way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Codeception assertion methods usually starts with `see`.
`have` methods do some setup work, like inserting record to database.

All `see` methods have `dontSee` counterparts.

So the method you had been looking for is `dontSeeInRepository` method of [Doctrine2 module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Doctrine2#dontSeeInRepository)

Comment: Thanks @Naktibalda. I may not have expressed myself correctly but, what I'm looking for is not how to perform an assertion (see/dontSee) but rather build the scenario previous to the execution of the method under test (The Given part of the test)